# Getting started with parsing (MediaWiki) API

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest, mediawiki-api

I want to create an iOS App that can parse the MediaWiki API so I can display articles etc.

I found [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)  but the developer is no longer working on it.
What should I use instead of this?
Or what documentations should I read to get started with this topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't worked with writing async networking code on iOS, then I would start with the [URL Loading System Programming Guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) first. You can use another wrapper library like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) if you prefer another level of abstraction, though I would still suggestion learning the URL Loading System as a first step.